# Can't change password policy on Azure VM (joined to Domain Services Domain)

Tags: group-policy, azure, virtual-machines, entra-domain-services

We have an Azure VM (Windows Server 2012 R2) using AAD DS as the domain. I have both an O365 account in the domain (used to originally join the VM to the domain) and a local admin account on the machine.

I'm not able to modify the password policy with either account. (GPO > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Account Policies> Password Policy > Maximum password age)

The password policy sections of the GP have little lock icons.

Where/how can these settings be altered? There does not appear to be a place to edit group policy in the Azure portal for AAD DS. Is there some way to unlock these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not able to modify the password policy with either account.

You needs the credentials of a user account belonging to the **AAD DC Administrators group** in your directory, to administer Group Policy for your managed domain. You can install the AD administration tools on the managed-domain VM.

1. Open Server Manager. Click Add Roles and Features.
2. On the Features page, click to expand the Remote Server Administration Tools node and then click to expand the *Role Administration Tools* node. Select *AD DS and AD LDS Tools* feature from the list of role administration tools.
3. Finish the installation.

Then you will find two containers called **AADDC Computers** and **AADDC Users** respectively. From **AADDC Users** container, you will see the **AAD DC Administrators group**.

For more details: [Administer an Azure Active Directory Domain Services managed domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-domain).

> Where/how can these settings be altered? There does not appear to be a
>   place to edit group policy in the Azure portal for AAD DS. Is there
>   some way to unlock these settings?

You need to install Group Policy tools on the virtual machine.

- Launch the Server Manager, On the Features page, select the *Group Policy Management* feature. Then complete the installation.
- Click Group Policy Management to launch the Group Policy Management console.  Find group policies for your managed domain.
- Right-click the GPO and click Edit... to customize the built-in GPO. The Group Policy Configuration Editor tool enables you to customize the GPO.

You can now use the Group Policy Management Editor console to edit the built-in GPO.

For more details: [Administer Group Policy on an Azure AD Domain Services managed domain](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-group-policy)